# How to set percentHeight in PercentRelativeLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-percentrelativelayout

I want to set the height of PercentRelativeLayout in percentage.

```
PercentRelativeLayout layout = new PercentRelativeLayout(this);
        PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams llp = new PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams(PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 50%);
        layout.setLayoutParams(llp);

        myLayout.addView(layout);
```

I suppose to use percentHeight(50%) in LayoutParams, not Match_Parent or Wrap_Content.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root);
PercentRelativeLayout percentRelativeLayout = new PercentRelativeLayout(this);
percentRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
rootLayout.addView(percentRelativeLayout);

Button button = new Button(this);
percentRelativeLayout.addView(button);
PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (PercentRelativeLayout.LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
PercentLayoutHelper.PercentLayoutInfo info = params.getPercentLayoutInfo();
info.heightPercent = 0.5f;
```

Will have this output:

[image: PercentRelativeLayout takes half the screen height]